# About strategy pattern and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strategy-pattern

I want to incorporate the **strategy pattern** in my application.

I have stored under **lib** the following classes.

```
class Network
  def search
    raise "NO"
  end

  def w_read
    raise "NO"
  end
  #...
end
```

AND

```
class FacebookClass < Network
  def search
    # FacebookClass specific...
  end

  def w_read
    raise OneError.new("...")
  end
end
```

AND

```
class TwitterClass < Network
  def search
    # TwitterClass specific...
  end

  def w_read
    # TwitterClass specific...
  end

  def write
    # TwitterClass specific...
  end
end
```

Now I want to call the method **search** of **TwitterClass** from **app/model/network_searcher.rb**. How can I do that? Did I implemented the **strategy pattern** here successfully?

Comment: What do these classes represent?

Comment: I want to have a general class that defines search and then two sub-classes, which define specifically the Twitter-Search and the Facebook-Search, so I can always pick one of them.

Comment: I smell Java here.
Probably you don't need that FinalInformation base class (which looks like a Java interface/abstract class).
In ruby it is enough to have two classes with same method signatures to have the common 'interface'. But it depends what you are trying to do, and you didn't give us much information.

Comment: I have to classes: TwitterClass and FacebookClass in lib. Now I want to start my search from the class SocialNetwork in model. In the future I want so add the class GooglePlus. All this classes have a specific method called search.

Answer (score 6):

Going by the example in the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Example), I think your `app/model/network_searcher` should be something like this

```
class NetworkSearcher
  def initialize(search_class)
    @search_class = search_class
  end

  def search_social
    @search_class.search
  end

  def w_read_social
    @search_class.w_read
  end

  def write_social
    @search_class.write
  end
end
```

Then in controller or where you want to invoke it, you can call like this:

```
search_class = TwitterClass.new # or FacebookClass.new
network_searcher = NetworkSearch.new(search_class)
network_searcher.search_social # or network_searcher.w_read_social or network_searcher.write_social
```

Also if you are keeping these classes in lib, for Rails 3, inorder to get these classes autoloaded, you need to add this line to `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

and also follow the naming convention for the filenames in Rails (for example `TwitterClass` should be named `twitter_class.rb`). Otherwise you will have to require these files wherever you are using these classes.

Comment: I spot some bad naming here. `search_class` should be something like `searcher`. You don't really pass a class constant here in `NetworkSearch`, you pass an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is used to allow the algorithm to use to be selected at runtime. Without more details it's hard to say if this is appropriate to your problem. Assuming that it is then what you need is a way to set the search on your model and you can then use the selected algorithm elsewhere in your model. e.g.

```
class TheInformation
  attr_writer :searcher

  def other_method
    ..
    # can use the selected searcher here
    @searcher.search
    ..
  end
end
```

Does that help?